# Writing many rows into a file efficently

Tags: c#, io, stream

I have a process that gets many rows of a table. This rows need to be reported in a report sheet. What I'm doing for the moment is too slow, because there are so many rows (600.000 <= x)-Rows. 
I'll show what I'm doing now to give you an idea of what I'm doing:

```
 private void ShowNotFoundRows() {

        report += "NOT FOUND - Rows";
        report += "\r\n";
        report += "In Current:";
        report += "\r\n";
        string Columns = "|";
        foreach (string header in currentModel.Columns) {
            Columns += header + "|";
        }
        report += Columns;
        report += "\r\n";
        foreach (string row in newModel.Keys) {
            report += row + "\r\n";
        }
        report += "\r\n";
        report += "In New:";
        report += "\r\n";
        report += Columns;
        report += "\r\n";
        foreach (string row in currentModel.Keys) {
            report += row + "\r\n";
        }
}
```

and after:

```
        private void CreateReportFile() {
        MyLog.WriteToLog("Creating ReportFile "+newModel.TableName, MyLog.Messages.Info);
        string dir = Settings.Default.ReportFolder + "\\" + directoryName + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        try {
            File.WriteAllText(dir + "\\Report " + newModel.TableName, report);
        } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e) {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing you can do is use a `StringBuilder` instead of doing so many string concatenations. You might see a significant improvement with that little change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using StringBuilder and see where that gets you.  You're copying in a lot of memory with stringx = stringx+ stringy because it creates a new object and copies all of it into the new object.  I have a feeling that'll get you where you need to be. Stringbuilder by contrast preallocates memory.

Beyond that, you could do things like divide the data into partitions, and multithread that, and then combine the results at the end.

Comment: Thank you! thats what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a StringBuilder which is more efficient ad adding strings. In c# "+" creates a new string everytime!
Use AppendLine, Append, AppendFormat, etc., and when finished ToString().

```
 var report = new StringBuilder();
 report.AppendLine("NOT FOUND - Rows");
 report.AppendLine("In Current:");
 ...
```

Then

```
File.WriteAllText(dir + "\\Report " + newModel.TableName, report.ToString());
```

Comment: Sry that i didn't gave u a tick. But your awnser in combination with a other awnser was the solution for my problem. So feel free to imagine a hypothetical tick :P. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder will help you to build the report in memory much more efficiently. But the result is still hold in memory completly. To avoid this you could write partial results (e.g. line by line) using a `FileStream`.